# How to get the number of count including the duplicates in javascript from JSON?

Tags: javascript

I have the JSON as following ,

```
var json =
         [
            {"cardAid":"ALPHG","displayName":"ALPHG","SequenceNumber":"0","port":"A"},
            {"cardAid":"ALPHG","displayName":"ALPHG","SequenceNumber":"1","port":"B"},
            {"cardAid":"SFD","displayName":"SFD","SequenceNumber":"2","port":"C"},
            {"cardAid":"SFD","displayName":"SFD","SequenceNumber":"3","port":"D"},
            {"cardAid":"ALPHG","displayName":"ALPHG","SequenceNumber":"4","port":"E"},
            {"cardAid":"ALPHG","displayName":"ALPHG","SequenceNumber":"5","port":"F"},
            {"cardAid":"BETA","displayName":"BETA","SequenceNumber":"6","port":"G"}
        ];
```

I used the code to parse this JSON from this link,
[TO Get the number of Count from JSON in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822671/to-get-the-number-of-count-from-json-in-javascript)

```
function count(arr) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var name = arr[i].cardAid;
        var port = arr[i].port;
        if (name in map){
            map[name].Count++;
            map[name].Port += ',' + port;
        } else {
            map[name] = { Count: 1, Port: port };
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

This Function parses the JSON using cardAid as the key and gives output as,

```
{
  ALPHG: { Count: 4, Port: "A,B,E,F" },
  SFD: { Count: 2, Port: "C,D" },
  BETA: { Count: 1, Port: "G" }
}
```

But i need the output based on the SequenceNumber in the JSON,

```
{
  ALPHG: { Count: 2, Port: "A,B" },
  SFD: { Count: 2, Port: "C,D" },
  ALPHG: { Count: 2, Port: "E,F" },
  BETA: { Count: 1, Port: "G" }
}
```

How can i put this duplicate name in the Map based on the SequenceNumber from JSON

Comment: Your desired output is missing a comma after the second `ALPHG` object. Furthermore, the desired output isn't valid because you can't have two object properties with the same name. They'll just overwrite one another, or in the case of you parser, it looks like it is concatenating them together.

Comment: Corrected the desired output

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure what you want.... this out put could be possible if you limit the coun to 2 then group the port again in another, is that what you want?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao The second object property with the same name will overwrite the first. You can't have two properties with the same exact name. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2vb94qc/)...

Comment: @War10ck I'm so sorry , was a typo on to -> not (really meant) thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @AlvaroJoao No worries. All is well. :)

Comment: this questions should be erased or edited to smth logically right.....

Comment: @ Alvaro Joao : I want to limit based on the Sequence Number in JSON..
Ex: Sequence Number (0,1) as ALPHG, so want to group as ,
ALPHG: { Count: 2, Port: "A,B" }
Basically im grouping the adjacent JSON objects if "cardAid" is same in the consecutive sequenceNumber..

Comment: @ShanthammaDS  you should make it clear in the question,I got it after seeing the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be close to what you had in mind ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs6oh26e/2/)), I opted to having Port as an array instead of a string. But I am a bit confused as SequenceNumber has no impact in this logic, maybe elements should be sorted first by SequenceNumber?

```
function count(data) {
    var result = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var cardAid = data[i].cardAid;

        if (!(cardAid in result)) {
            result[cardAid] = [];
        }

        // Check if a new "sequence" needs to be created
        if (i == 0 || data[i-1].cardAid != cardAid) {
            result[cardAid].push({ Count: 0, Port: [] });
        }

        // Append item to the latest sequence
        var lastIndex = result[cardAid].length - 1;
        ++result[cardAid][lastIndex].Count;
        result[cardAid][lastIndex].Port.push(data[i].port);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "ALPHG": [
    {
      "Count": 2,
      "Port": [ "A", "B" ]
    },
    {
      "Count": 2,
      "Port": [ "E", "F" ]
    }
  ],
  "SFD": [
    {
      "Count": 2,
      "Port": [ "C", "D" ]
    }
  ],
  "BETA": [
    {
      "Count": 1,
      "Port": [ "G" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is what i needed.. 
But i don't want to Append item to the latest sequence.
I want to create a New Sequence 
Ex:"ALPHG_1": [
    {
      "Count": 2,
      "Port": [ "E", "F" ]
    },

Comment: An other try at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rs6oh26e/11/) has object keys `"ALPHG_0", "SFD_0", "ALPHG_1", "BETA_0"`. But I imagine this would be trickier to use in other parts of the code.